# What is the underlying system that google uses for implementing GC task queues

Tags: queue, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Google Cloud provides [task queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/), both a push mechanism and a pull mechanism. I'm wondering what technology they have used to implement these, and if this technology is open source.

Answer (score 2):

The task queue service is based on Google internal technologies. You can read more about them in the [2nd chapter](https://landing.google.com/sre/book/chapters/production-environment.html) of the Google SRE book.